# AngularJS Refresh Select Tag with dynamic content at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

**EDIT - lots of changes**

After my page loads, I have some javascript function calls that return data which will be used in my markup to populate  tag options.

Currently the issue is this: When the values are changed by the javascript outside ( and even inside the AngularJS controller). The view is not being updated. I have tried wrapping scope assignments in $scope.$apply(...) however this just results in a $digest() already in progress error.

AngularJS Code:

```
app.service('userService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var userModel = {
        qGroupZero: '',
        qGroupOne: '',
        qGroupTwo: ''
    };

    var states = '';

    return{
        getUserModel: function() {
            return userModel;
        },
        getStates: function() {
            return states;
        },
        loadChallengeQuestions: function() {
            var userEnrollmentChallenge = getChallengeQuestions();
            console.log('loadChallengeQuestions()');

            userModel.qGroupZero = userEnrollmentChallenge.challengeQuestions.questionGroup[0];
            userModel.qGroupOne = userEnrollmentChallenge.challengeQuestions.questionGroup[1];
            userModel.qGroupTwo = userEnrollmentChallenge.challengeQuestions.questionGroup[2];
        },
        loadStates: function(callback) {
            console.log('loadStates()');
            return $http.get('content/states.json').then(function(result) {
                states = result.data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('EnrollmentController', ['$scope', 'userService', '$http', function($scope, userService, $http) { //Dependencies and Constructor function.

    $scope.userService = userService;
    $scope.states = [];

    userService.loadChallengeQuestions();
    var userModel = userService.getUserModel();
    $scope.qGroupZero = userModel.qGroupZero.challengeQuestion; //<-- This assignment is not updated in the view.

    userService.loadStates().then(function(result) {
        $scope.states = userService.getStates(); //<-- This assignment is not updated in the view.
    });

}]);
```

The content of challengeQuestion is a JSON array of 7 items.

The Markup:

```
<select ng-model="selectionOne"
    name="question1"
    ng-options="opt as opt.questionText for opt in qGroupZero">
</select>
<select ng-model="state"
     name="state"
     ng-options="opt as opt.abbreviation for opt in states"
     class="required">
</select>
```

So at this point. I have all my resources. And I just need to find a way to get AngularJS to re-evaluate the ng-options value (a $scope.value) and redraw the content? I think I'm saying that right...

Why do I feel that this should be easy? And yet three days later here I am :D

Thanks for reading and helping!!!

Comment: What does your JSON object look like? If you are getting something returned, the way you set your ng-options directive could be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the angular $http service and promise objects instead?

```
app.service('userService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var userModel: {
        qGroupZero: '',
        qGroupOne: '',
        qGroupTwo: ''
    };

    var states = '';

    return{
        getUserModel: function(){
            return userModel;
        },
        getStates: function(){
            return states;
        },
        loadChallengeQuestions: function(userEnrollmentChallenge) {
            console.log('loadChallengeQuestions()');
            userModel.qGroupZero = userEnrollmentChallenge.challengeQuestions.questionGroup[0];
            userModel.qGroupOne = userEnrollmentChallenge.challengeQuestions.questionGroup[1];
            userModel.qGroupTwo = userEnrollmentChallenge.challengeQuestions.questionGroup[2];
        },
        loadStates: function(){
            return $http.get('content/states.json').then(function(result){
                states = result.data;
            });
        }
    }
});

app.controller('EnrollmentController', ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService) { //Dependencies and Constructor function.
    $scope.states = [];

    userService.loadStates().then(function(result){
        var userModel = userService.getUserModel();
        $scope.states = userService.getStates();
        $scope.qGroupZero = userModel.qGroupZero.challengeQuestion;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Working on your solution Kevin, thanks for the quick reply. Currently $scope.states is not being assigned a value. When I debugger on $scope.states = userService.getStates(), getStates() returns the array if evaluated in the console. However when I view the scope, $scope.states = ''. Also tried $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.states = userService.getStates();
        }); - This causes an error..

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. Updated the code. States wouldn't have been set when it was calling getStates before, that needs to be called in the then function as well

Comment: I've implemented your solution exactly as you have it. But the binding of the data to $scope.states must not be calling $digest(). I tried wrapping the assignment in $apply but that just results in an error. My real question at this point is how to update a <section> tag content when the ng-options changes state. Since this doesnt seem to be happening